# How to implement this Desmos roll function in Unity

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, animation, math

I was looking for a way to create a roll out effect just like this in a 2D Unity project
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mrfrugwvm5

The problem is I'm not that goot at math, so I'm not sure how to translate the function to say a line renderer's points.

Can someone help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to break this down a bit there are actually two functions involved.

The first

```
y = -1 { 0 <= X <= p }
```

is quite trivial: In the range `0` to `P` paint a straight line with fixed `y = -1`.

The other one is returning `x` and `y` coordinates and basically translates to

```
var x = (1 - t / totalLength) * Mathf.Sin(t) + p;
var y = -(1 - t / totalLength) * Mathf.Cos(t);
```

There are also some ranges involved such as

- `{0 <= p <= 14}` => `p` lies within `0` and `14`

  You will see the number `14` at various places => This is the maximum total length of the line when it is fully unrolled
- `{0 <= t <= 30}` => Not sure why they used a `30` here - the result is actually the same as with `14`, again the total length
- `{t < 14 - p}` => This limits `t` further down so the actual range is `{0 <= t <= 14 - p}`

The `p` basically determines at which point the swirl starts and how big the range for `t` is.

So as far as I can tell in a `LineRenderer` this somewhat boils down to e.g.

```
public static class LineRendererExtensions
{
    public static void DrawRolledLine(this LineRenderer line, float totalLength, float p, int maxPoints = 51, float swirlRadius = 1f)
    {
        // ensure p is between 0 and 1
        p = Mathf.Clamp01(p);

        // As a performance boost do not use more points than necessary
        // The higher p the less swirl => requires less points to draw
        var resolution = Mathf.CeilToInt(Mathf.Lerp(0, maxPoints, 1 - p));
        // ensure we have at least 2 points to draw a line
        resolution = Mathf.Max(2, resolution);
        
        // map p to the total length
        p *= totalLength;
        
        // calculate the range for the t value
        var maxT = (totalLength - p) / swirlRadius;

        // prepare the points array
        var points = new Vector3[resolution];
        
        // begin of straight line - for convenience I move the whole thing up by 1
        points[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        // calculate the points of the swirl
        for (var i = 1; i < resolution; i++)
        {
            // spread the points equally over the range of t
            var t = (i - 1f) / (resolution - 1f) * maxT;

            // use given functions to calculate x and y positions
            var x = (1 - t / totalLength) * Mathf.Sin(t) * swirlRadius + p;
            var y = (-(1 - t / totalLength) * Mathf.Cos(t) + 1) * swirlRadius; // moving up by 1 * radius

            points[i] = new Vector3(x, y);
        }

        // finally apply the calculated points to the line renderer
        line.positionCount = resolution;
        line.SetPositions(points);
    }
}
```

As you can see as parameters I added a bit more flexibility

- `totalLength`: The maximum length of the line when unrolled
- `p`: Factor in the range `{0, 1}` => This will be mapped into `{0, totalLength}`
- `maxPoints`: Up to how many points to use to draw the result

  If there is lesser swirl this resolution is reduced for better performance
- `swirlRadius`: In case you want the swirl part to have a different radius than the default of `1`

I also modified the functions slightly so that the line is always at `0` instead.

---

As a little demo use e.g. this component

```
[ExecuteAlways] // <- also run in edit mode
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private LineRenderer m_LineRenderer;

    [SerializeField]
    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    private float m_P = 0.5f;

    [SerializeField]
    [Min(0)]
    private int m_Resolution = 51;

    [SerializeField]
    private float m_TotalLength = 14.0f;

    [SerializeField]
    [Min(Mathf.Epsilon)]
    private float m_Radius = 1.0f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!m_LineRenderer)
        {
            m_LineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

            if (!m_LineRenderer)
            {
                m_LineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
                m_LineRenderer.startWidth = 0.1f;
                m_LineRenderer.endWidth = 0.1f;
            }
        }

        m_LineRenderer.DrawRolledLine(m_TotalLength, m_P, m_Resolution, m_Radius);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @s_marcell I think you can adjust the tiling of the line - by default it is `stretch` meaning it stretches the texture according to the distances between points and in my implementation and for simplicity and performance for the entire straight line you always use only 2 ^^ I think you can just switch that to `Tile` see [`LineTextureMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineTextureMode.html)

Comment: I did all that, also set the wrap mode of the sprite to repeat, and the mesh type to Full Rect in the import settings, however it repeats the whole sprite and not just the part within the borders set in the sprite editor. I think this is a shader thing, and I didn't want to mess with that.